# Magento 2.2 - Unable to create customer attribute programatically using InstallData

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, magento2.2

I have created a new module to create customer attribute. The same was working perfectly in previous magento 2 versions. But in magento 2.2 its not working. Could you pls check into that.

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\AttributeManager\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();


        $attributesInfo = [
            'nettermspo' => [
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' =>99,
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Is eligible for NET TERMS PO ?',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 99,
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 1,
                'default' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'system' => 0,
                'group' => 'Account Information',
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }
        $nettermspoAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'nettermspo');
        $nettermspoAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $nettermspoAttribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend you to use simple online module creator for Magento 2 that allowes you to create customer attribute and choose its details. 
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

After creating module check the following:

- is module listed in app/etc/config.php and is allowed? if not, run Magento module enable command http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html
- run magento setup:upgrade
- run magento setup:di:compile
- is installed attribute present in eav_attribute table?
- run magento indexer:reindex and cache:clean
- remove var/di var_view_preprocesses/ var/generation files
- clear pub/static (except .htaccess file)

After all that the installed attribute should be visible in customer forms selected in setup script.

**UPDATE:**

In Magento 2.2 I'm using following approach with CustomerSetupFactory for example in app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php.

```
...
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
...
protected $customerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}
...
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

    $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.8') < 0) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create();
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_buzzshopper', [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Label',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'note' => 'Some note',
                'length' => 1,
                'sort_order' => 106,
                'position' => 106,
                'system' => false,
                'adminhtml_only' => 1,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false
            ]
        );
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_buzzshopper');
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']
        );
        $attribute->setData('is_user_defined', true);
        $attribute->setData('is_required', false);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Attribute created that way is shown in admin forms only as boolean "switch" button. See "used_in_forms" data for forms list.
Just notice. Call save() function on attribute it self isn't best practice. Its maybe even depraceted approach, because entities must not be responsible for their own persistence - however it works for simple demonstration.

Comment: Will this work on magento 2.2.2?

Comment: Have updated my answer with working example on Magento ver. 2.2.0. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue on our client's Magento Open Source 2.2.1 (Community), and the problem appeared to be with the `user_defined` property. As soon as I flipped it to `false` in the install script, or `eav_attribute.is_user_defined = 0` directly in the database, the attributes immediately started showing up on the admin customer edit form.

So in your case, Try setting `$attributesInfo['nettermspo']['user_defined'] = false`. Or rather:

```
...
$attributesInfo = [
    'nettermspo' => [
        'user_defined' => false,
        ...
    ]
];
...
```

Comment: that's the wrong approach! Magento 2.2 introduced 'used_in_forms' for attributes. You should manipulate this.

Comment: In my case, this fix was actually used in conjunction with the `used_in_forms` approach. I even verified that the new attributes were added to the `customer_form_attribute` table after finding out that using the correct AttributeRepository approach didn't work correctly. I'm more than happy to collaborate to find the correct solution as that's what I'm always looking for. I would also suggest that if you are going to call me out on the wrong approach that you contribute an answer of your own.

Comment: Thanks @floorz, flipping the user_defined property worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that from Magento 2.2 onwards, `user_defined` has to be false in order for the `used_in_forms` approach to work.

The only other option I see, is to add the field to the UI component declaration by adding a file to your module `view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` with contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="my_custom_field" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```